# Ethereum Mining: Do miners get a fee AND create new ether as a reward?

Tags: blockchain, mining, ether, gas, bitcoin

So far what I get is that when I send ether or any contract via the ethereum network that I then have to pay for this transaction by paying gas (which again has a price in ether and so on). So miners try to solve this transaction by building the next block and if they achieve it they broadcast this to the network. So I guess one miner will solve my transaction and this one miner will get the whole fee.

***(This is kind of my first question: how many miners get my fee for this transaction? Since I think that only one will achieve to solve it, right?)***

On the other hand I also know that within the bitcoin network miners get rewarded by mining bitcoins. Thus new bitcoins are created. But isn't that also true for the ethereum network? Aren't miners also creating new ether by mining?

**So miners must get the fee plus they get rewarded with newly created ether?**

Comment: Also related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13201/if-everyone-runs-the-same-transaction-why-does-only-the-miner-get-gas?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Only one miner collects fees, but sometimes, more than one miner gets a reward. [Uncle blocks](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/31/uncle-rate-transaction-fee-analysis/) level the playing field for smaller-scale miners to mitigate the kind of centralization seen with Bitcoin. Thus, if two people both arrive at a solution for the next block, they can *both* be rewarded. [Selfish mining](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/selfish-mining-a-25-attack-against-the-bitcoin-network-1383578440/)'s benefits are reduced, thus mitigating a 25% attack on the blockchain (which Bitcoin is susceptible to). Miners of future blocks are incentivized to include the competing solution, thus resulting in an uncle block and an overall stronger network.